# Gulp Equivalent (from Grunt) - Multiple src files

Tags: gruntjs, gulp

I've been tinkering around with [GulpJS](http://gulpjs.com/) and believe it's a good next step from Grunt, but am having a few issues with the syntax in comparison.

Here is a section from my `Gruntfile.js`:

```
concat: {
    ie: {
        options: {
            separator: "\n\n"
        },
        src: [
            "bower_components/selectivizr/selectivizr.js",
            "bower_components/respond/dest/respond.min.js",
            "bower_components/REM-unit-polyfill/js/rem.js"
        ],
        dest: "assets/js/build/ie.js"
    },
    dist: {
        options: {
            separator: "\n\n"
        },
        src: [
            // Foundation Vendor
            "bower_components/foundation/js/vendor/fastclick.js",
            "bower_components/foundation/js/vendor/placeholder.js",
            // Foundation Core
            "bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.js",
            "bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.abide.js",
            "bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.accordion.js",
            "bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.alert.js",
            "bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.clearing.js",
            "bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js",
            "bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.interchange.js",
            "bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.joyride.js",
            "bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.magellan.js",
            "bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.offcanvas.js",
            "bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.orbit.js",
            "bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.reveal.js",
            "bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.tab.js",
            "bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.tooltip.js",
            "bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js",
            // Custom Vendor

            // Project
            "assets/js/src/_init.js"

            ],
        dest: "assets/js/build/scripts.js"
    }
}
```

So as you can see, I'm specifying specific files (since I don't want to pull in an entire directory as you normally see it done), which seems simple enough. All tuts I've found for Gulp seem to follow that regex format:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src("assets/js/src/_init.js")
    .pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js/build'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(livereload(server))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js/build'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Scripts task complete' }));
});
```

But putting in a comma-separated list into that `src` portion doesn't work -- how do we pass an array of files to that method?

It looks like I can separate my IE specific scripts using multiple streams in one, like so:

```
gulp.task('test', function(cb) {
    return es.concat(
        gulp.src('bootstrap/js/*.js')
            .pipe(gulp.dest('public/bootstrap')),
        gulp.src('jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js')
            .pipe(gulp.dest('public/jquery'))
    );
});
```

But a quick comment on if that is correct would be great too. Thanks!

Comment: completely off topic and irrelevant to your question, but are you compiling sass/compass with gulp as well?

Comment: Still on Grunt at the moment, but moved from Compass to just use grunt-contrib-sass and grunt-autoprefixer; does everything I need.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpsrcglobs-options):

> #### globs
>
> Type: `String` or `Array`
>
> Glob or globs to read.

In other words, pass in an array of strings, like:

```js
gulp.src(['file1.js', 'file2.js']).pipe(...)
//       ^                      ^
//       '-------- Array -------'
```

Please note that this is the *exact* same format as Grunt.  It's an array of globs, not a comma-separated list.

Comment: Thats fantastic, I have read couple of other blogs and people just dont know about it and are using alternatives.